Using csi secrets store volume mounted cert with ingress controller
As the docs state (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) kubernetes secrets are not too safe to use and one should strive to use external stores.
But I am struggling to understand the progress that is being made in the ingress controller world. It seems still todate the current ingress controllers only work fine with kubernetes secrets as an intermediary store for tls certificates.
Take the stack that Microsoft provides as an example. They have done a great job by providing a managed ingress controller on top of Azure Kubernetes Service. This managed ingress controller is leveraging nginx.
They have added a special annotation that under the hood leverages csi secrets store and Azure Key Vault. The managed service generates a SecretProviderClass based on your ingress resource and triggers the creation of a kubernetes secret.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl#create-the-ingress-that-uses-a-host-name-and-a-certificate-from-azure-key-vault
The manifest example they give is as follows:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: <KeyVaultCertificateUri>
  name: aks-helloworld
  namespace: hello-web-app-routing
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
  - host: <Hostname>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - <Hostname>
    secretName: keyvault-<your ingress name>

As you see the annotation they use is kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri.
To summarize my point of interest: I would like to learn the current state of affairs with regards to tls certificate integration into ingress controllers without the use of kubernetes secrets as an intermediary.
I also found this google spreadsheet with an interesting overview of many ingress controllers and their feature set:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191WWNpjJ2za6-nbG4ZoUMXMpUK8KlCIosvQB0f-oq3k/edit?gid=1061522953#gid=1061522953
But I can't see a relevant line to my question.
Maybe DAPR is the way forward. DAPR provides a provider agnostic API for pulling secrets from external stores. Ref: https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/secrets/secrets-overview/
Do you have any pointers and insights to share? Maybe there are already implementations around.
